# 'this' inside an IIFE | Same as local scope?

Tags: javascript, iife

If I have an IIFE does this refer to the local scope?

```
(function(){

    var $a;   
    $a = Su.$a

    // this.$a = Su.$a; // can I replace with this

})();
```

I'm asking because I need `Su.$a` available everywhere in my IIFE.

But I don't want to call `Su.$a`, I want to call `$a`.

is saying `this.$a` the same as saying `var $a` when var it top-level scoped?

Answer (score 6):

No.

`this` is set by a few things, described by [MDN / `this` Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), but in short:

- the global object, at the top level scope
- `obj`, when executing `obj.func(...)`
- `obj`, when executing `func.apply(obj, [...])` or `func.call(obj, ...)`
  or the global object, if `obj` is `null` or `undefined`
- a new object with prototype `func.prototype`, when calling `new func(...)`
- the event target, if `elem.addEventListener('event', func, ...)` and `event` is fired on `elem`

There's a few differences and additions in newer JavaScript, but that's pretty much it.  `this` is unrelated to `function` scope.

Comment: Is there any way to reference local scope then, or would that just be redundant because you are "in" local scope, I just thought for consistency sake there might be a way

Comment: @HiroProtagonist No, there is not.  You can do the opposite -- `with (obj)` will add it to the scope chain -- but it is highly disrecommended.

Comment: PHP has this and self which refer to the current object and class respectively...but no equiv. in js I guess.

Answer (score 5):

No, they are different.

`var $a`, then the `$a` is local variable in the function scope.

But if you use `this.$a`, because this is a self execution function, `this` is `window` in this case, `this.$a` is same as `window.$a`, so you are using a global variable `$a` instead.

Comment: never thought about it, but strange that this refers to the calling "mechanism"...where as in classical OO this refers to the the current object...very confusing if you compare an contrast.